# repo SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, shell, repo

I run the following commands to get `repo`:

```
mkdir ~/bin
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
PATH=${PATH}:~/bin
```

I have 2 python versions(2.7 and 3.7) in my computer so I created an alias to python3 in `~/.bashrc` because this is required by `repo`

```
alias python=python3
```

Then run following commands to get the yocto project:

```
repo init -u https://xxxx -b release/bxxx
```

I got this error:

```
File "/Path/.repo/repo/main.py", line 79
file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if I run `python3 ~/bin/repo init -u https:/blablabla` there is no problem, so some how executing the first command calls to `python2`. Any explanation

Comment: This isn't actually a python question. It's to do with the way Linux parses shebang lines, which doesn't work with alias' as shown in this answer https://serverfault.com/a/1050710

The repo file starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python` and the line at which it is failing is a buggy error that uses python3 syntax to alert the user that they're using python2. Not your fault that this wasn't clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points to the explanation you're looking for:

1. Your alias isn't being used when your OS looks for an interpreter to execute the repo file. It starts with the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python` which might be pointing to python 2.7 on your machine. Try just writing `/usr/bin/env python` on your terminal and seeing which version of python console is launched. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1050710) for suggestions.
2. I think the reason you're getting this syntax error is because you are indeed using python2.7 and the repo file's import  `from __future__ import print_function` doesn't seem to be working as expected (which would make that syntax okay). Not sure why that's happening though.

Comment: As indicated in the error message, it comes from a different file which presumably does not have this `import`. Brief experimentation reveals that `repo` ends up trying to call `python` as a subprocess of itself and/or `exec` it.

Comment: @tripleee Good point, I'd for some reason assumed it was just unpacked from that file. Could you share what your experimentation was? Checking running processes or something?

Comment: I just tried to run it, and got an error message about Python being unavailable, probably because it somehow failed to anticipate my use of `pyenv`.